# initializing private variable for subsequent usage

Tags: f#

Can you initialize a private value in a module, and then later call another function to read the value? I'm getting an empty string though.

**data/Credentials.fs**

```
type Credentials = {
    mutable clientId: string; 
}
```

**Authentication.fs**

```
module Authentication =

    let private credentials = {
        clientId = "old"; 
    }

    let init (claims: Credentials) =
         credentials.clientId <- claims.clientId // updating value

     let requestToken =
          printfn "reading %s\n" credentials.clientId // reading updated value
```

**AuthenticationTest.fs**

```
 let credentials = { 
     clientId = "new"; 
 }

 init credentials // set credentials
 requestToken     // read credentials
```

**Expected output:**

> reading new

**Actual Output:**

> reading old

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`requestToken` is defined as variable, which contains result of `printfn "reading %s\n" credentials.clientId`. What you want is probably

```
let requestToken () =
      printfn "reading %s\n" credentials.clientId
...
requestToken ()
```

Comment: oh thanks a lot, I've been struggling with it for long

Comment: by the way is it fine to program like this, I hope it's not against idiomatic functional programming? i.e. to pass all parameters to every function to make a total independent isolated function, please enlighten to get the understanding right

Comment: @App2015 If you're using the `mutable` keyword, it's a good sign you're not doing idiomatic functional programming.

Comment: @TheInnerLight thanks, I had doubts too and in my use case if I use idiomatic approach then the callers have to pass credentials to every function defined in this library along with other required params, an idea is to curry them, please enlighten more.

Comment: @App2015 It's hard to help without broader context of the problem but if you have functions that either depend upon or transform some supplied credentials then passing them explicitly (and returning new immutable credentials when they need to be changed) is probably the correct approach.

Comment: I'll post another question to address this, the idea is I'm building a library of functions that requests access tokens to some API while passing it some credentials, a typical api workflow. Once I obtain token I pass it along with every subsequent api REST calls and also ensure that token is renewed before expiry, are you on code review?